# Have this tag [truncated]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The tag [truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncated) has no tag wiki, with an excerpt of

> Truncation is the term for limiting the number of digits right of the decimal point, by discarding the least significant ones.

It is currently used very inconsistently, for example:

- [File truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66588751/5958455)
- [Code output truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66372979/5958455)
- [Database content truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66322055/5958455)
- [`org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66108113/5958455)
- [Truncated function (about Maths and Statistics)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65253003/5958455)
- and many more

With its current excerpt, it appears to be a decent fit with [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precision). But after closer examination, it's better gone as well. Additionally, both [truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate) and [truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncation) exist, with the former having a more complete tag wiki and more questions. So I'm proposing:

- Truncate all questions from [truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncated)
- Merge [truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncation) into → [truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate)

Comment: The title is a bait and switch! I was thinking that this was a burnination request!

Comment: Bug: I think there was more to the tag wiki, but it was unfortunately [truncated].

Answer (score 14):

I agree, with one minor quibble: I'd go the other way and merge [truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate) into [truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncation), but keep the tag wiki/excerpt from [truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate).

The concept itself is "truncation," as the wiki for [truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate) even notes (emphasis added):

> Data **truncation** is the automatic or deliberate shortening of data.

Comment: I would vote to keep both the wiki and the excerpt from `truncate`.

Comment: @iBug Good point. I did mean both, but it's good to be explicit.  Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents: I think `truncate` has its own meaning, because of SQL `TRUNCATE TABLE`, and [also C stdlib `truncate()` / `ftruncate()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) functions.

Shouldn't we keep `truncation` for the general concept, **and** `truncate` for SQL + C function specific questions?

Agreed, `truncated` could be merged in one of these.

Comment: In that case, it's better to have a tag like `sql-truncate-table` for the former usage, and add `ftruncate` for the POSIX system call.